# Deriving a formula for an arbitrary term in $1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, \ldots$

Tags: pattern-recognition

A sequence of numbers is given as: 
$$1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, \text{and so on}$$
(Each integer $n$ is repeated $n$ times.) What will be the 50th term of that sequence?

Let's say $x=50$. Then solving $x=n(n+1)/2$ gives the value of $n$ (rounded off to nearest integer).

My question is: If I make a small change in the above pattern, can we have a direct formula to calculate $n$?

> The new pattern is : 
>   $$1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, \ldots$$
>   i.e., $1$ and $2$ are repeated once, and $n$ is repeated $(n-1)$ times.
>
> How can we derive a formula for this pattern?

Comment: You can ignore the existence of the $1$, and then notice that the sequence $2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,\dots$ is simply the sequence where each entry is one more than the corresponding entry in the earlier mentioned sequence.

Comment: Yeah i get that, but let's say i'm only provided with 'x' and i need to find the corresponding 'n' for it according to the new sequence

Answer (score 0):

Using JMoravitz hint above, you can replace $x$ with $x-1$ and $n$ with $n-1$ and now your formula is $x-1=(n-1)(n)/2$.  Whatever you get for n should be rounded up to the nearest integer if it isn't an integer already.

For example for $x=5$, we have $4 = (n-1)(n)/2 \to 8 = (n-1)(n) \to n^2-n-8=0 \to n=3.37$ which rounds up to 4.

Comment: Ultimately this amounts to the formula
$$
n = \left \lceil 
\frac 12 (\sqrt{8x - 7} + 1)
\right \rceil
$$